# SWIG c++ to C# error unable to find entry point SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_xxxx

Tags: c#, c++, swig

So I got this simple C++ code that I try to wrap using swig 3.0.2 to generate the C# equivalent.

So here is the c++ code

myclass.hpp

```
#ifndef __MYCLASS__
#define __MYCLASS__

class myclass {
public:
    int add(int b, int c);
};

#endif
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.hpp"

int myclass::add(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

myclass.i

```
%module mymodule

%{
#include "myclass.hpp"
%}

%include "myclass.hpp"
```

So here is the swig command

```
swig -csharp -c++ -outdir csharp myclass.i
```

And here is the compilation command using MinGW

```
g++ -shared -I./ myclass_wrap.cxx myclass.cpp -o mymodule.dll
```

So then I try to use the generate code by swig in a console application and I get the following error:

> Unable to find an entry point named
>   'SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_mymodule' in DLL 'mymodule'.

So it is loading the mymodule.dll correctly but can't find the SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_mymodule which seems weird ... it is present in the myclass_wrap.cxx with what seems to be the correct export keyword `__declspec(dllexport)`

Thanks for the help,

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've found the issue so others who runs into the same issue can have a solution.

Adding `-add-stdcall-alias` to the compiler fixed the issue:

```
g++ -shared -I./ myclass_wrap.cxx myclass.cpp -o mymodule.dll -add-stdcall-alias
```

Using a DLL explorer viewer software I noticed the functions ended with `MyFunctionName@XX`, which I believe cause the entrynotfoundexception since it is looking for `MyFunctionName` and not `MyFunctionName@XX`.

So swig generated the c code with `__stdcall` and MinGW generated those `MyFunctionName@XX` when in `__stdcall`

More information can be found here : http://wyw.dcweb.cn/stdcall.htm

Cheers,